# How do I return the sum of an array, with this code to start it off?

Tags: java, arrays, bluej

So this is what I have:

```
public static void Positive () {
    int limit = 50;
    for(int i=1; i <= limit; i++){
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
    }
}
```

That prints out all numbers 1-50 with a loop

How do I return the sum of this using a loop?

Comment: Here's a hint - Have a counter inside the loop, and add ```i``` to it each time.

Comment: @Siddhartha probably you meant "outside"

Comment: No, don't do that. Have a counter *outside* the loop. If it was inside, it would be local to the loop and get destroyed after each iteration.

Comment: Yeah oops i meant increment it inside

Comment: Maybe something like [Returning a Value from a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do

```
public static void Positive () {
int limit = 50;
int total = 0;
for(int i=1; i <= limit; i++){
    total = total + i;
   }
System.out.print(total);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the return type to int.

```
public static int Positive () {
    int limit = 50;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=1; i <= limit; i++){
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```
int sum = 0; 

for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {

sum += i; 

}
```

You havent cleared yet that you want to return the value or just print it from the function so you can use either of the approach in answers of your question. One with `int` type can return the value and print as well